# htaccess contact form upload folder - how to hide it

Tags: .htaccess, security

I have got a contact form on my website with file attachment as well, that has been restricted only to pictures. Although if I type in `example.com/uploads/` all the files are accessible by anyone. Is htaccess the best way to hide it? Also how could I do that in a safe manner, without messing up the contact form?

I have tried this, but it blocks the whole website

```
deny from all
<Files ~ “^w+.(gif|jpe?g|png)$”>
order deny,allow
allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: What do you do with these pictures after upload? If they are being displayed on a webpage, they will need to be publicly available.

Comment: No, it should only be accessible through ftp to the owner of the website

Answer (score 0):

> if I type in `example.com/uploads/` all the files are accessible

You mean you get a directory listing? This can be disabled in .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
```

To actively block all HTTP requests for files in the `/uploads` directory (since you state in comments that these are only ever accessed over FTP) then all you need is (in your root .htaccess file):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^uploads - [F]
```

This will respond with a 403 Forbidden for all requests that start `/uploads`.

Comment: I have tried this one as well but, it does not do anything. I placed the htaccess in the root folder.

Comment: This would need to go towards the start of your .htaccess file, before other mod_rewrite directives - to avoid any conflict. (Also, this won't work if you have already put a .htaccess file - with mod_rewrite directives - in the `/uploads` folder itself (as in the other answer), unless you also have `RewriteOptions inherit` set in that .htaccess file.)

Answer (score 0):

Just to block access to `example.com/uploads/` you can place this rule in `/uploads/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ - [F]
```

Comment: This one actually does the job, but how easy would it be to rewrite my htaccess file? Can i block that to be rewritten as it is in the upload folder and not hard to find.

Comment: No one can overwrite your .htaccess unless you have some code level vulnerability. By default Apache blocks any web request to `.htaccess`

Comment: Also if it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.